# how to call http call inside the for loop after success of before http call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I want to call the api after completing the first is success.But in my code it call the api before the first one was completed

```
  for(var w=0;w<Ids.length;w++){
      $scope.msgObject = {
               "SenderID":$scope.pageId,
               "PageID" : $scope.pageId,
                "Date":Date.now().toString(),
              };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
           url: '///url',
           async:true,
            data: $scope.msgObject,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }})
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log("success posting");
              }
            })
             .catch(function(response){

            });
      $(".messageInput").val('');


      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you clarify your question?  Each iteration of your loop will fire an asynchronous API call to your URL, and the loop will not wait for each response.  The code in each of your then() functions will run (asynchronously) as the responses return.  Is this what you are expecting? (edited - spelling)

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33741475/5547718. In your case, you have to dynnamically create the myAsynchFunctions array by simply pushing the ajax request.

Comment: this question is a dupe. you will find the answer on google. this question is identical to like 60% of the other questions in the javascript tab.

Comment: @KarlWenzel I want the loop to wait for the response and go to next iteration after receiving the response of first call

Comment: If you want the loop to wait, then you should not use async: true, however this function would then block JS execution in the meantime.  Some of the other comments offered seem to offer a better strategy.

Comment: "sync" AJAX calls are not recommended at all (also, deprecated e.g. in Chrome)

Answer (score 4):

```js
function asyncForEach(arr, cb) {
    return arr.reduce((p,c)=>{
        return p.then(()=> cb(c));
    }, Promise.resolve());
}

function fetch(id) {
  return new Promise(resolve=>
    setTimeout(resolve, 100)) // replace with your AJAX call
      .then(()=>console.log('success posting', id));
}

function done() {
    console.log('all done!');
}

const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
asyncForEach(ids, fetch).then(done);
```

Answer (score 0):

put your loop inside THEN
something like

```
function urPostMethod(url){

$scope.msgObject = {
               "SenderID":$scope.pageId,
               "PageID" : $scope.pageId,
                "Date":Date.now().toString(),
              };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
           url: url,
           async:true,
            data: $scope.msgObject,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }})
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log("success posting");
              while(Ids.length>0)urPostMethod(Ids.pop());
              }
            })
             .catch(function(response){

            });
      $(".messageInput").val('');


      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but how would that stop the second api call

Comment: it won't call the second until the first call is done

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to mix async and sync operations together which is not logical at all.

If you need to call those API's in order of your elements in your array, you may use a different approach like pipe the requests using Defer:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred(),  
    x = 0, // Loop index
    Ids = [],
    msgObject = {
       "SenderID":$scope.pageId,
       "PageID" : $scope.pageId,
        "Date":Date.now().toString(),
      };


    callAjax = function (value) {
        var dfdAjax = $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '///url',
            async:true,
            data: msgObject,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }})
        .then(function(response) {
           dfdAjax.resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(function(response){
            dfdAjax.reject(response);
        });        

        return dfdAjax.promise();
    },

    requestAjax = function (value) {
        return callAjax(value);
    };

dfd.resolve();

for (x = 1; x <= Ids.length; x++) {

    dfdNext = dfdNext.pipe(function () {        
        return requestAjax(value).
            done(function(response) {
                // Process the response here.
            });

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$q.all()` and simplify your syntax, you'll just need to inject the [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service.

The below code adds all the promises returned by `$http` into a single array, executes the promises using `$q.all()` and then gathers their results.

```
var requests = [];

for(var w = 0; w < Ids.length; w++) {    
    var req = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '///url',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: {
          SenderID: $scope.pageId,
          PageID: $scope.pageId,
          Date: Date.now().toString(),
        }
    })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // handle err 
        });

    requests.push(req);
}

$q.all(requests)
    .then(function (results) {
        // handle results
    });;
```