# Fast-csv read several files synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, parsing, asynchronous

I'm trying to read several files synchronously with fast-csv, it should looks like:

```
read file 1
execute something while reading
read file 2
execute something while reading (it must be execute after first execution's file that's why I need to do this synchronously)
...
```

Here is my code simplified:

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const PROCEDURES = [
    { "name": "p1", "file": "p1.csv" },
    { "name": "p2", "file": "p2.csv" },
];

const launchProcedure = (name, file) => {

    try {   
        const fs = require("fs");
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {
            encoding: 'utf8'
        });
        console.log('launching parsing...');

        stream.once('readable', () => {
        // ignore first line
        let chunk;
        while (null !== (chunk = stream.read(1))) {
            if (chunk == '\n') {
                break;
            }
        }

            // CSV parsing
            const csvStream = csv.fromStream(stream, {
                renameHeaders: false,
                headers: true,
                delimiter: ',',
                rowDelimiter: '\n',
                quoteHeaders: false,
                quoteColumns: false
            }).on("data", data => {
                console.log('procedure execution...');
                // I execute a procedure...

            }).on("error", error => {
                logger.error(error);
            }).on("end", data => {
                logger.info(data);
            });
         });

    }
    catch (e) {
        logger.info(e);
    }
}

PROCEDURES.forEach(procedure => {
    launchProcedure(procedure.name, procedure.file);
});
```

Output will be:

```
launching parsing...
launching parsing...
procedure execution...
procedure execution...
```

Problem is on stream.once but I used this to ignore first line. I tried to promisify my function and use async await...
( I had a similar problem when executing my procedure and I solved it by using csvStream.pause() and csvStream.resume() ).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I found a solution in the meantime before seiing your answers (sorry for posting later) !

```
const launchProcedure = (name, file, callback) => {

    try {   
        const fs = require("fs");
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {
            encoding: 'utf8'
        });
        console.log('launching parsing...');

        stream.once('readable', () => {
        // ignore first line
        let chunk;
        while (null !== (chunk = stream.read(1))) {
            if (chunk == '\n') {
                break;
            }
        }

            // CSV parsing
            const csvStream = csv.fromStream(stream, {
                renameHeaders: false,
                headers: true,
                delimiter: ',',
                rowDelimiter: '\n',
                quoteHeaders: false,
                quoteColumns: false
            }).on("data", data => {
                console.log('procedure execution...');
                // I execute a procedure...

            }).on("error", error => {
                logger.error(error);
            }).on("end", data => {
                logger.info(data);
                callback();
            });
         });

    }
    catch (e) {
        logger.info(e);
    }
}
async.eachSeries(PROCEDURES, (procedure, callback) => {
        launchProcedure(db, procedure.name, procedure.file, callback);        
    }, error => {
        if (error) {
            logger.error(error);
        }
        else {
            logger.info("done");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using promises seems like a good way to solve this. Be aware though, that when you create a new Promise with `new Promise(executor)`, the `executor` is [executed immediately](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). So you need to delay it until the previous promise has been executed.

To "promisify" the `launchProcedure` function, you need to return a new Promise at the start of the function:

```
const launchProcedure = (name, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

And then you need to call `resolve` (for success) and `reject` (for failure) whenever the parsing has finished.

Finally we need to string together the promises:

```
let promise = launchProcedure(PROCEDURES[0].name, PROCEDURES[0].file);
for (let i = 1; i < PROCEDURES.length; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(() => launchProcedure(PROCEDURES[i].name, PROCEDURES[i].file));
}
```

Note that I use a lambda function within the `then` to delay the creation of the Promise. (By the way, there are also [nicer ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33741475/1492977) to string together promises.)

The final code looks like this:

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const PROCEDURES = [
    { "name": "p1", "file": "p1.csv" },
    { "name": "p2", "file": "p2.csv" },
];

const launchProcedure = (name, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {   
            const fs = require("fs");
            const stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {
                encoding: 'utf8'
            });
            console.log('launching parsing...');

            stream.once('readable', () => {
                // ignore first line
                let chunk;
                while (null !== (chunk = stream.read(1))) {
                    if (chunk == '\n') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // CSV parsing
                const csvStream = csv.fromStream(stream, {
                    renameHeaders: false,
                    headers: true,
                    delimiter: ',',
                    rowDelimiter: '\n',
                    quoteHeaders: false,
                    quoteColumns: false
                }).on("data", data => {
                    console.log('procedure execution...');
                    // I execute a procedure...

                }).on("error", error => {
                    logger.error(error);
                    reject(error);
                }).on("end", data => {
                    logger.info(data);
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            logger.info(e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}

let promise = launchProcedure(PROCEDURES[0].name, PROCEDURES[0].file);
for (let i = 1; i < PROCEDURES.length; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(() => launchProcedure(PROCEDURES[i].name, PROCEDURES[i].file));
}
promise.then(() => { console.log('all files parsed'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `launchProcedure` has to be `async` in order to use `await`. Another problem is that using `async`/`await` together with `Array.forEach` is not the best choice ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/305949)).

You can do this using the "for-of" loop and await inside the loop body:

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const fs = require('fs');
const PROCEDURES = [
    { "name": "p1", "file": "p1.csv" },
    { "name": "p2", "file": "p2.csv" },
];

const launchProcedure = async (name, file) => {

    try {   
        // only require this once in the file (you require each time `launchProcedure` is getting called)
        // const fs = require("fs"); 
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {
            encoding: 'utf8'
        });

        console.log('launching parsing...');

        // wait for the readable (or error) event
        const ready = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            stream.on('readable', resolve);
            stream.on('error', reject);
        })
        .then(() => true)
        .catch(() => false);

        console.log('file is ready: ', ready)

        if (!ready) {
            throw new Error(`Unable to read file (file-name: "${file}")`);
        }

        // ignore first line
        let chunk;
        while (null !== (chunk = stream.read(1))) {
            if (chunk == '\n') {
                break;
            }
        }

        // CSV parsing
        const csvStream = csv.fromStream(stream, {
            renameHeaders: false,
            headers: true,
            delimiter: ',',
            rowDelimiter: '\n',
            quoteHeaders: false,
            quoteColumns: false
        }).on("data", data => {
            console.log('procedure execution...');
            // I execute a procedure...

        }).on("error", error => {
            logger.error(error);
        }).on("end", data => {
            logger.info(data);
        });

        console.log(`Done reading file (file-name: "${file}")`);
    }
    catch (e) {
        logger.info(e);
    }
}


// Wrap your iteration over the `PROCEDURES` array into an async function (this makes `await` available inside the function)
// Then use "for-of" here instead of for each to have full async support.
const runProcedures = async (procedures) => {
    for (procedure of PROCEDURES) {
        await launchProcedure(procedure.name, procedure.file);
    }
}

runProcedures(PROCEDURES);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
launching parsing...
file is ready:  true
Done reading file (file-name: "p1.csv")
launching parsing...
file is ready:  true
Done reading file (file-name: "p2.csv")
```

Comment: Don't you have "procedure execution..." for each line of the file after "file is ready:  true" ?

Comment: @Curse No, I don't. This is probably because my csv files don't fit your CSV options. I didn't check that, tbh.